# Received some error data from DHT12 sensor

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, wiringpi

1. SCL pin->Raspberry SCL pin. SDA pin->Raspberry SDA pin. Vcc->5V. GND->0V

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int dht;
    wiringPiSetup();
    dht=wiringPiI2CSetup(0x5c);

    while(1)
    {   
        int humid_int_digit=0,humid_scale=0, temp_int_bit=0, temp_scale=0, check=0;
        humid_int_digit=wiringPiI2CReadReg8(dht,0x00);
        humid_scale=wiringPiI2CReadReg8(dht,0x01);
        temp_int_bit=wiringPiI2CReadReg8(dht,0x02);
        temp_scale=wiringPiI2CReadReg8(dht,0x03);
        check=wiringPiI2CReadReg8(dht,0x04);
        delay(2000);

        printf("\nHumid digit: %d\n",humid_int_digit);
        printf("Humid scale: %d\n",humid_scale);
        printf("Temp: %d\n",temp_int_bit);
        printf("Temp scale: %d\n",temp_scale);
        printf("Check: %d\n",check);
    }
}
```

2. The result are 255 for each register.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @aventurin Why is this better suited for somewhere else? This is clearly a programming question.

Comment: Do you have a voltage level shifter between the sensor and the Pi? The Pi's I2C pins are not 5v tolerant.

Comment: Sounds like electrical issue: a) voltage level; b) pull-up resistors.